# Calling function on #DIV rather than window()

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, target

I wrote this script which effectively hides a toolbar dependent on browser *window().width*.
I have since realised that due to the way I want to work that width out..:

'$csspagewidth2= $csspagewidth * 2;'

.. that instead of *window().width* I could do with this being against a *#DIV.width*. But when I try to change the window().width to #main-content. It fails to work. Can anyone help please?

```
if ($("#main-content").width() < 600) {
       $( "#toolbarright").hide();
}
else {
        $("#toolbarright").show();
}

$("#main-content").resize(function() {
   windowWidth = $(this).width();//you need to use this for changable values
   if ( windowWidth < 600) {

       $( "#toolbarright").hide();

   } else if ( windowWidth > 600) {

        $("#toolbarright").show();

   }
 });
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ablueman/vdgeLsgL/16/

Context: https://www.ablueman.co.uk/testbench/layout.php

Comment: It would probably help if you showed us the JS that didn't work instead of the PHP that does.

Comment: Editted Q and jsFiddle - It seems to break the entire script by changing window to main-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
if ($("#maincontent").width() < 600){
       $( "#toolbarright").hide();
} else { $("#toolbarright").show();}
});


$(window).resize(function() {
if ($("#maincontent").width() < 600){
       $( "#toolbarright").hide();
} else { $("#toolbarright").show();}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ablueman/vdgeLsgL/

Answer (score 1):

`$(main-content)` will take the `main` variable (`undefined`) and subtract from it the `content` variable (also `undefined`) giving you `NaN`, which will then be used to try to instantiate a `jQuery` object. It won't find any matching elements in the DOM.

You want `$("#main-content")`

Comment: Which still seems to break the rest of the script. http://jsfiddle.net/ablueman/vdgeLsgL/15/ -- It should look like http://jsfiddle.net/ablueman/vdgeLsgL/14/ -- So whilst you have explained one mistake I made :) it doesn't fix the script.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy with CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px){
       #toolbarright { display:none; }
}
```

### [DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/w7djurj9/)

> **Update 1:**

**JQuery**

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    $('#main-content').each(function(){
        var box = $(this);        
        var width = box.width();
        var height = box.height();
        if ( width < 600) {
            box.find( "#toolbarright").hide();
        } else if ( width > 600) {
            box.find("#toolbarright").show();
        }          
        $('.size').html(width+'x'+height+' (r: '+(width/height).toFixed(3)+')');
    });
}).trigger('resize');
```

**CSS**

```
#main-content 
{
    margin: 120px;
    position: relative;
}
#toolbarright 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    outline: 1px solid grey;
    height:100px;
}
```

### [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/6eabcmok/1/)

Comment: Nice solution but effectively the same as window().width. But if you have a look at context link that wont work for me.

Comment: I appreciate all the work you have done, but your demo appears broken. I cant position elements the point of this is to be fluid. What I need to do is figure out how to replace window with #main-content

Comment: I update ``DEMO2``.
But who wants to do it should consider all aspects.``:-)``

Comment: ``box`` similar to ``window``.

Comment: and if someone has a very small browser window then opens this with your script. It would load and be there even though its too small, they would have to resize for it then to dissapear.